# Online programming editor

Tags: editor

For a school project i need to write or use a online programming editor. It is a part of a bigger project. I thought of a java application, php/html/javascript or flash.

I have a couple of things i could do:

- Find a good working application and edit it so it works with the rest of the project
- Find good parts for a editor and make it working my self (syntax highlighter, auto-indent, autocompletion, etc.)
- Combination of those two

Does anybody know a good editor or have tips for this project or a editor?

Thanks for reading,

Leon

Comment: Wow ! That's very advanced for a school project.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For the syntax highlighting and basic editing part, check out my recent question [Textarea that can do syntax highlighting on the fly?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1619167/textarea-that-can-do-syntax-highlighting-on-the-fly)

Solutions presented there:

- [CodeMirror](http://marijn.haverbeke.nl/codemirror/)
- [Bespin](https://bespin.mozilla.com/) (Mozilla only, but great)

For the rest - autocompletion etc. - ... Check out the Wikipedia article [Comparison of JavaScript-based source code editors](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comparison_of_JavaScript-based_source_code_editors)
Interested to see what other suggestions come up.

Answer (score 0):

[Bespin](https://bespin.mozillalabs.com/) comes to mind. Though it might be too bleeding edge, depending on how the rest of the project is built/meant to be used (but hey, programmers love bleeding edge).

Answer (score 0):

If you decide to use PHP/HTML/CSS/JavaScript, see [GeSHi](http://qbnz.com/highlighter/) for syntax highlighting.

Comment: Geshi is great but it can't do highlighting on the fly (i.e. inside the editor), can it?

Comment: No, it can't. This is a general limitation of HTML textareas and has actually nothing to do with Geshi itself.

Answer (score 0):

I have a side project developed with ACE.

It connects to your server through SFTP and allows you to create new files,read and edit all from your browser with your file tree at sidebar.

Demo at [TePe](http://editor.diki.io)

Code at [Github Repo](https://github.com/diki/tepe)

Answer (score 0):

I found  [Cobalah Editor](http://dul.web.id/cobalah-editor.php) it's also built on CodeMirror but with some customization. There are some themes available we can set, increase or decrease font size.