# working with xml snippets in CKEditor

Tags: ckeditor

I am Using CKEditor in my application where the users can write blogs, create pages etc..,
Source mode is disabled for the editor. Writing xml in the editor's text area is not retained after saving the content. I clearly see that the content got HTML Encoded and the same is supplied as input to the CKEditor's textarea.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Works as designed. Whatever you enter into the WYSIWYG area, will get HTML encoded. How would you want to behave it differently?

If you want a text editor for writing XML, maybe the answers to this question are useful: [Textarea that can do syntax highlighting on the fly?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1619167/textarea-that-can-do-syntax-highlighting-on-the-fly)

Comment: But the same should be shown as xml snippet on view of the content isnt?

Comment: @Ama I do not understand what you mean, can you clarify?

Comment: I typed xml in the editor like <prop></prop> and saved the content.
I supplied the same content to the editor. Nothing is shown in the text area.

Answer (score 0):

I too want CKEditor to support XML tags, but I understand that you can't just type them into the main window - anything typed here is assumed to be actual content, not tagging, and therefore gets encoded.

What I'd *like* to do is define a list of styles that cause a tag of my choosing to be used, e.g. if the user chooses the 'example' style, CKEDitor does `<x>content</x>`. Unfortunately I haven't had much success with this, despite hacking the dtd.js file.

My current solution is to define a list of styles but map them to a standard HTML tag, then put my desired XML tag name in as an attribute. I'll then need to write some XSLT that transforms the data later.

```
CKEDITOR.stylesSet.add('myStyles',
[{
  name: 'Example sentence', 
  element: 'span', 
  attributes: {'class': 'example', 'data-xmlTag': 'x'} 
}];        

config.stylesSet = 'myStyles';
```

`element` specifies a standard HTML tag – I use `<span>` if I want the XML to be inline and `<div>` if I want it to be block level. The `data-xmlTag` attribute says what XML tag I actually wanted to use (`x` in this case). The `class` allows me to define some styles in CSS and means I can group several XML tags under one class name. To define some CSS:

```
config.contentsCss = CKEDITOR.basePath+'tagStyles.css';
```