# Is there a decent html editor that works in-browser?

Tags: html, text-editor

I am using Wordpress and I want site editors to be able to write html by hand (no wysiwyg).  However, everyone knows that editing html in a textarea with no colorization or other code editor features is difficult.  Does anyone know of a solution -- maybe a textarea replacement, browser extension, or the like?

There are plenty of wysiwyg editors, but I'm specifically looking for an in-browser code editor that handles HTML.  It would be a bonus if it handled javascript and CSS as well.

Comment: possible duplicate of [textarea with syntax / code highlighting](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1505761/textarea-with-syntax-code-highlighting)

Comment: and http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1619167/textarea-that-can-do-syntax-highlighting-on-the-fly

Comment: This is pretty much the same question as those.  Sorry.

Comment: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comparison_of_JavaScript-based_source_code_editors  from the other threads.  EditArea, CodeMirror, CodePress, and Bespin are all possible solutions.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1505761/textarea-with-syntax-code-highlighting
and [Textarea that can do syntax highlighting on the fly?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1619167/textarea-that-can-do-syntax-highlighting-on-the-fly)

From those threads, a list of in-browser html editors:  http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comparison_of_JavaScript-based_source_code_editors

EditArea, CodeMirror, CodePress, and Bespin all seem active and capable.  Using WMD for markdown is another option.

Answer (score 4):

Have you considered using [Markdown](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Markdown) (as StackOverflow does) ?

In my opinion, it is very easy to write and format text using Markdown. It is easy to get started with [WMD](http://wmd-editor.com/), which is a java-script only Markdown editor.

Comment: This is a good idea.  I was thinking they would edit minimal HTML elements but markdown would enforce that.  I will look into it.

Comment: The original [AttackLabs WMD](http://wmd-editor.com/) site is no longer available, the [StackOverflow WMD-new](https://code.google.com/p/wmd-new/) branch was hosted at Google Code for several years, and is now at [GitHub](https://github.com/derobins/wmd/tree/master) with a note "No longer maintained - Please use [PageDown](https://code.google.com/p/pagedown/) instead". PageDown is also hosted on Google Code, and is now an archived project.

Answer (score 2):

Mozilla [bespin](http://mozillalabs.com/bespin) is a javascript text editor that can be embedded.

Comment: Trying bespin which even has a bookmarklet.  Seems extremely limited right now and it can't word-wrap which makes it difficult when converting a textarea on the fly.

Comment: Bespin is now known as [SkyWriter](https://mozillalabs.com/en-US/skywriter/) and is currently considered inactive. Some of the SkyWriter code ended up in [Ace](http://ace.ajax.org/), which is the project they are now promoting.

Answer (score 0):

I'm quite fond of [XStandard](http://www.xstandard.com/). It produces proper valid HTML (Only the XHTML varieties), has a realistic WYSIWYG editor with the option to also edit the source directly, and has a free version (which has been enough for uses I've put it to).