# RIch text input box - overflowing issue

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, syntax-highlighting

I have created a rich text input box where the purpose is to highlight parentheses that match or don't match up etc. Basically simple highlighting for `()`'s. This all works great for what I am doing, the only problem I have encountered so far is when you overflow the input, the underlying html element remains the same which messes stuff up.

Live example here: http://jsfiddle.net/Axvgf/

Just type in a bunch of letters in the input and you'll see the problem.

Any help would be appreciated!

Thanks in advance.

Edit: If my approach is not going to work or is too flawed, I accept different suggestions and/or solutions.

Edit2: I have tried a new approach, using `contenteditable` but that runs into a bunch of problems with the caret position every time. Here's my attempt: http://jsfiddle.net/Axvgf/25/

Comment: I would not use an input. I think it's best to capture keyboard events and simulate the position of the cursor.

Comment: @Scipion: Do you mean ignoring the input element entirely and using `contenteditable=true` or similar?

Comment: yes but contenteditable is not the best solution. I thought of using textarea and change the style or something like google docs

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if this would meet your needs, but I would take a look at the projects referenced in solutions to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1619167/textarea-that-can-do-syntax-highlighting-on-the-fly) about syntax highlighting in a textarea. Many of them are open source and seeing how others have successfully tackled the problem may give you some ideas for your project.