# Format JSON string using js/jquery to readable format in textarea

Tags: javascript, jquery, json, stringify

I have a js variable that contains an object. I'm passing the data in that object to a html `<textarea>` using jquery. I'm also passing my variable through `JSON.stringify` so the code looks like so:

```
$("#textarea1").val(JSON.stringify(myVarData, null, "\t"));
```

The problem is twofold.

1. In the `<textarea>` the data is enclosed in curly brackets `{}` as it's still in JSON - How can I remove them before sending it to the `<textarea>`? Basically plain text.
2. The data is well formatted as

   ```
   { "property":value, 
     "property":value,
     "property":value }
   ```

which is okay if I had simple data, but in one of the properties, I have a value that looks like so:

```
"report_data":"{"subjects":[{"subject_name":"ENGLISH","parent_subject_name":null,"teacher_id":39,"initials":"A.A.F","use_for_grading":true,"marks":{"MID-TERM 1 2018":{"mark":87,"grade_weight":100,"grade":"A"}},"overall_mark":"87","overall_grade":"A","remarks":"Excellent"},{"subject_name":"MATHEMATICS","parent_subject_name":null,"teacher_id":40,"initials":"B.K.K","use_for_grading":true,"marks":{"MID-TERM 1 2018":{"mark":80,"grade_weight":100,"grade":"A"}},"overall_mark":"80","overall_grade":"A","remarks":"Excellent"},
```

How can I get this `value` data formatted to be easily readable like in (1) above? Is it possible to choose only what I want from the `value`? I tried using `JSON.parse` after the `stringify` but got `[object Object]` as the result.

**NOTE** This isn't a duplicate of [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26320525/prettify-json-data-in-textarea-input) as that question is about copying **an object** to a text box. In part one of my question - I want the data out of the curly brackets - which is no longer JSON. And that solution proposes what I'm already using.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [prettify json data in textarea input](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26320525/prettify-json-data-in-textarea-input)

Comment: `JSON.parse` is to get a JS object from a JSON string.

Comment: @31piy it not a duplicate as the solution to that question uses `stringify` and indentation on the `stringify` which I'm already using in my qusestion. And this is specific to removing the curly brackets.

Comment: @Clint_A -- the comment says _possible duplicate_. If others find it an exact duplicate, they will also vote to close this question. Otherwise, someone will answer it.

Comment: https://github.com/google/code-prettify

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/substring

Comment: what you exactly want to display in the text-area

Comment: @Sravan I want the JSON data as formatted plain text in the text-area. I've already solved the first part of my question or removing the curly brackets using the answer given by DT Teja below. Now I'm  trying the format the value that has an array of values (part 2 of the question)

Comment: formAT the value means, you also need to remove all the braces from array?

Comment: @Sravan Yes - I'd like to remove all the braces from the array

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```js
var a = {"report_data":{"subjects":[{"subject_name":"ENGLISH","parent_subject_name":null,"teacher_id":39,"initials":"A.A.F","use_for_grading":true,"marks":{"MID-TERM 1 2018":{"mark":87,"grade_weight":100,"grade":"A"}},"overall_mark":"87","overall_grade":"A","remarks":"Excellent"},{"subject_name":"MATHEMATICS","parent_subject_name":null,"teacher_id":40,"initials":"B.K.K","use_for_grading":true,"marks":{"MID-TERM 1 2018":{"mark":80,"grade_weight":100,"grade":"A"}},"overall_mark":"80","overall_grade":"A","remarks":"Excellent"}]}}
console.log(JSON.stringify(a).replace(/[\[\]']+/g,'').replace(/[\{\}']+/g,''))
var final = JSON.stringify(a).replace(/[\[\]']+/g,'').replace(/[\{\}']+/g,'');
$("#textarea1").val(JSON.stringify(final, null, "\t"));
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<html>
<body>
<div id = "textarea1"></div>
</body>
</html>
```

The fast and optimized solution can be using `regular expression`.

**No need to even loop here**

just use,

**`JSON.stringify(myVarData).replace(/[\[\]']+/g,'').replace(/[\{\}']+/g,'')`**

Comment: Thanks. This is actually what I needed in my quest

Comment: glad to help you. :)

Answer (score 1):

1) You can use javascript substring method to remove the curly brackets {}

eg:JSON.stringify(myVarData).substring(1,JSON.stringify(myVarData).length-1)

2) To choose the property in a value object, select the property by parsing through parent object and then do stringify

eg: to print marks of first subject
     JSON.stringify(myVarData.report_data.subjects[0].marks)

Comment: Thanks. Part 1 of your answer solved my first problem. I'll test the second part using a for loop as I don't wan't to hard code what I want to select as the number of subjects are variable