# Textarea html tag with support `css` code

Tags: javascript, html, css

I'm looking for `textarea` so I can write `css` code inside it. And have a good graphic appearance for displaying `css` code

As in the picture below:

[image]

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Textarea that can do syntax highlighting on the fly?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1619167/textarea-that-can-do-syntax-highlighting-on-the-fly)

Comment: You can use https://codemirror.net

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There can be really one of two ways to do that: either you will implement it yourself OR use ready made libraries. Solutions like that exist in great variety and it could save you a lot of time to use one of following or find a similar one:

- [Edit Area](https://www.cdolivet.com/editarea/)
- [highlight.js](https://highlightjs.org/)
- [CodeMirror](https://codemirror.net/)