# In a contenteditable div, when I type a word after a colored html tag, the typed word also gets colored like the tag by mistake. How to avoid it?

Tags: javascript, html, css, node.js

Please see the example below. It creates a contenteditable div with some colored HTML tags. When I try to write immediately after a colored tag, then the next word is colored too. The word also gets colored if I use the space after the tag. However, the word following the tag should not be colored, because I only specified the red color of `["DIV", "H1", "P", "<", ">", "/"]`.

Example:

[image]

How can I avoid text coloring after red tags? (consider that Example1 and 2 is just an example text and that in the future I will add other tags with different colors). I would like the words typed after the html tags to be black as specified in the css, where `#editor` is with `color: black`

The problem should be in the `changeColor()` function.

P.S: Be careful not to use a solution that breaks the mouse pointer while writing and automatically moves the pointer to the second or third line, because apparently this can easily happen in the case of my code.

```js
function applyColoring(element) {
  var keywords = ["DIV", "H1", "P", "<", ">", "/"];

  var newHTML = "";
  // Loop through words
  str = element.innerText;
  (chunks = str
    .split(new RegExp(keywords.map((w) => `(${w})`).join("|"), "i"))
    .filter(Boolean)),
  (markup = chunks.reduce((acc, chunk) => {
    acc += keywords.includes(chunk.toUpperCase()) ?
      `<span class="statement">${chunk}</span>` :
      `<span class='other'>${chunk}</span>`;
    return acc;
  }, ""));
  element.innerHTML = markup;
}

// CHANGE COLOR
function changeColor() {
  var editor = document.getElementById("editor");
  applyColoring(editor);

  // Set cursor position to the end of text
  var child = editor.children;
  var range = document.createRange();
  var sel = window.getSelection();
  range.setStart(child[child.length - 1], 1);
  range.collapse(true);
  sel.removeAllRanges();
  sel.addRange(range);
  editor.focus();
}

function showPreview() {
  var editorContent = document.getElementById("editor").innerText;
  var frame = document.getElementById("preview-window");


  // Create a data URL with the HTML content
  var dataURL = "data:text/html;charset=utf-8," + encodeURIComponent(editorContent);

  // Set the iframe src attribute to the data URL
  frame.src = dataURL;
}
changeColor()

showPreview()
```

```css
#editor {
  width: 456px;
  height: 267px;
  padding: 10px;
  background-color: #ffffff;
  color: black;
  font-size: 14px;
  font-family: monospace;
  white-space: pre;
}

.statement {
  color: rgb(212, 42, 42);
}
```

```html
<div id="editor" contenteditable="true" oninput="showPreview();" onchange="changeColor();">&lt;h1>This is a Heading&lt;/h1> &lt;p>This is a paragraph.&lt;/p>
</div>

<h3>PREVIEW</h3>
<div class="preview-area">
  <iframe id="preview-window"></iframe>
</div>
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Textarea that can do syntax highlighting on the fly?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1619167/textarea-that-can-do-syntax-highlighting-on-the-fly)

Answer (score 0):

Moving changeColor inside of showPreview and delete onchange event,changeColor needs be triggered for every time inputing a word.

```html
<style>
  #editor {
    width: 456px;
    height: 267px;
    padding: 10px;
    background-color: #ffffff;
    color: black;
    font-size: 14px;
    font-family: monospace;
    white-space: pre;
  }
  
  .statement {
    color: rgb(212, 42, 42);
  }
</style>
<div id="editor" contenteditable="true" oninput="showPreview(event);" onclick="editorClick(event)">&lt;h1>This is a Heading&lt;/h1> &lt;p>This is a paragraph.&lt;/p></div>
<h3>PREVIEW</h3>
<div class="preview-area">
  <iframe id="preview-window"></iframe>
</div>
<script>
  var keywords = ["DIV", "H1", "P", "<", ">", "/"];
  const selection = window.getSelection()
  const children = document.getElementById("editor").children
  let position, currentIndex, isRed, length, value = null

  function getPosition() {
    return selection.getRangeAt(0).endOffset
  }
  function compute(val) {
    if (val === 'currentIndex') {
      if (keywords.join('').includes(children[currentIndex].innerText.toUpperCase())) {
        return
      }
      value === null ? currentIndex-- : currentIndex++
    } else {
      value === null ? position-- : position++
    }
  }
  function editorClick(e) {
    const range = selection.getRangeAt(0)
    length = children.length
    for (const index in children) {
      const ele = children[index]
      if (ele === range.commonAncestorContainer.parentElement) {
        isRed = ele.classList.value === 'statement'
        position = getPosition()
        currentIndex = +index
        break
      }
    }
  }
  function applyColoring(element) {
    var newHTML = "";
    // Loop through words
    str = element.innerText;
    (chunks = str
      .split(new RegExp(keywords.map((w) => `(${w})`).join("|"), "i"))
      .filter(Boolean)),
    (markup = chunks.reduce((acc, chunk) => {
      acc += keywords.includes(chunk.toUpperCase()) ?
        `<span class="statement">${chunk}</span>` :
        `<span class='other'>${chunk}</span>`;
      return acc;
    }, ""));
    element.innerHTML = markup;
    if (position === undefined) return
    if (length !== children.length) {
      if (position !== 0 && currentIndex !== 0) {
        currentIndex += children.length > length ? 1 : -1
      }
      position = 1
      if (children.length < length && children[currentIndex]) {
        position = children[currentIndex].innerText.length

      }
      length = children.length
    } else {
      if (isRed) {
        compute('currentIndex')
        position = 1
      } else {
        compute('position')
      }
    }
    if (currentIndex < 0) currentIndex = 0
    if (!children[currentIndex]) return
    const range = document.createRange();
    range.setStart(children[currentIndex].firstChild, position);
    range.collapse(true);
    selection.removeAllRanges();
    selection.addRange(range);
    const ele = range.commonAncestorContainer.parentElement
    isRed = ele.classList.value === 'statement'

  }
  // CHANGE COLOR
  function changeColor() {
    var editor = document.getElementById("editor");
    applyColoring(editor);
  }
  function showPreview(e) {
    if (e) value = e.data
    var editorContent = document.getElementById("editor").innerText;
    var frame = document.getElementById("preview-window");
    // Create a data URL with the HTML content
    var dataURL = "data:text/html;charset=utf-8," + encodeURIComponent(editorContent);
    // Set the iframe src attribute to the data URL
    frame.src = dataURL;
    changeColor()
  }
  showPreview()
</script>
```

Comment: I tried your code. Unfortunately there is a problem. I can no longer write in the editor. As soon as I write, the mouse pointer is automatically moved to the third line, so it is not possible to write. I didn't encounter this problem before. Could you review your code and improve it please? Thank you

Comment: I hope you will improve and correct your answer, because it currently doesn't help me :(

Comment: Its a difficult task and I had improved it took some hours  ,but maybe also some bugs

Comment: That's no good. There are still many bugs in your code. There is a slight improvement, but there are still many problems. You are kind and I appreciate your time. Thanks anyway, even if your answer wasn't helpful to me